# Field's object disappears once the lockerService is enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I tried to fill my object from intpuText but it seems that some fields disappear when LockerService is enabled. We can see the difference from the console log when I display my object fields :

**LockerService disabled :**

> 1. BillingCity:"TALENCE"
> 2. BillingPostalCode:"33400"
> 3. BillingStreet:"145 rue rgrge"
> 4. FirstName:"Dim"
> 5. Gender__c:"Male"
> 6. LastName:"Mon"
> 7. Marital_Status__c:"Single"
> 8. NumberOfChildren__c:1
> 9. PersonBirthdate:"1989-12-12"
> 10. PersonEmail:"dimi@fdg.fr"
> 11. Phone:"561451585787"
> 12. Profession_code__c:"4"
> 13. RecordTypeId:"012360000002uRzAAI"
> 14. URI__c:"new"
> 15. attributes:Object

**LockerService enabled:**

> 1. BillingPostalCode:(...)
> 2. BillingStreet:(...)
> 3. Gender__c:(...)
> 4. LastName:(...)
> 5. Marital_Status__c:(...)
> 6. NumberOfChildren__c:(...)
> 7. PersonBirthdate:(...)
> 8. Profession_code__c:(...)
> 9. RecordTypeId:(...)
> 10. URI__c:(...)
> 11. attributes:(...)

So we can see that some field have disappeared when LockerService is enabled.

here is the html file :

```
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
        <h3 class="irm">{!$Label.c.OwnerIsInsured}</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-1 irm-center">
            <c:CmpInputSelect DisplayMode="Buttons" field="Insurance_Quote__c.Insured__c" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Insured__c}" 
                              slds="{!v.slds}"/>
            <!--c:CmpInputSelect aura:id="Gender" DisplayMode="Radio" field="Account.Gender__c" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.Gender__c}" 
                          placeholder="Select Gender" slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.Gender}"/-->  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 ">
        <c:CmpInputSelect aura:id="Gender" DisplayMode="Radio" field="Account.Gender__c" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.Gender__c}" 
                          placeholder="Select Gender" slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.Gender}"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 irm-heightFix">
        <c:CmpInputText aura:id="LastName" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.LastName}" 
                        slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.LastName}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 ">
        <c:CmpInputText aura:id="FirstName" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.FirstName}" 
                        slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.FirstName}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
        <c:CmpInputDate aura:id="PersonBirthDate" object="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m}" valuePath="SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.PersonBirthdate" 
                        slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.BirthDate}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
        <c:CmpInputText aura:id="BillingStreet" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.BillingStreet}" 
                        slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.Address}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
        <c:CmpInputPostalCodeCity aura:id="PostalCodeCity" PostalCode="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.BillingPostalCode}"
                                  City="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.BillingCity}" slds="{!v.slds}"/>

    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
        <c:CmpInputEmail aura:id="Email" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.PersonEmail}" 
                         slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.Email}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
        <c:CmpInputPhone aura:id="Phone" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.Phone}" 
                         slds="{!v.slds}" label="{!$Label.c.Phone}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
        <c:CmpInputSelect aura:id="Profession" label="{!$Label.c.Profession}"
                          optionList="{!v.AvailableProfessionList}" value="{!v.Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r.Profession_code__c}" slds="{!v.slds}"/> 
    </div>

</div>
```

If anybody have already coped with this kind of issue and have a method to work around that will help me a lot !!

Comment: Are both snippits of console output for the same record? Locker service will remove properties with null values.

Comment: Is this still an issue? How is is the Insurance_Quote_m.SFObject.Contract_Holder__r attribute defined and populated with data? Adding additional properties to the object after the initial definition may be the root of some issues.